# Create an Android UI similar to keywords in stackoverflow

Tags: android, xml

I need to create a layout which is similar to this:

[image: layout image]

I want a similar layout in the keywords section. A user can enter the keywords. These are added to the textbox below. The max line allowed by the text box should be 2. I can add as many text as I want in the keywords section but it should only show me the latest keywords added. The 3 dots at the end of the 2nd line should show me a dialogue with all the list of tags added (not in scope for now).

Please guide me how can I get this.

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=chips

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, for these types of layouts where it's based on a menu screen, LinearLayout fits best. Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html). For the Tag Layout, I suggest using [AndroidTagGroup](https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup), an excellent library for this purpose.

You'd want to use a horizontal orientation LinearLayout. Here is what I came up with, tweak as needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ordered By (Person)"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Filmed By"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Keywords"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>
    <me.gujun.android.taggroup.TagGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:backgroundTint="#0026ff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I created my own custom layout which has a linear layout (vertical say L_Root), and inside that 2 Linear layout(horizontal say L1, L2). I am getting the width dynamically of the L1 and L2 and the tag and checking if there is any more in either L1 or L2 to add the tag.

Comment: if (line1Width - keywordWidth > 25)
    {
    line1Layout.addView(keywordTxt);
    line1Width = line1Width - keywordWidth;
    }
    else if (line2Width - keywordWidth > 30)
    {
    line2Layout.addView(keywordTxt);
    line2Width = line2Width - keywordWidth;
    }
    else
    {
    remaningKeywords.add(keywordTxt);
    }

Comment: @Uzair Please edit your original question to reflect this, it's hard to read code written in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to the UI and adding it here as suggested by @Faraz.

```
    private EditText keywordEdtTxt;
    private Button saveButn;
    private LinearLayout line1Layout, line2Layout, tempLayout;
    private int line1Width, line2Width, keywordWidth;
    private TextView keywordTxt;
    private ArrayList<TextView> remaningKeywords;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

       tempLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.temp_layout);

    line1Layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_line1);
    line1Layout.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            line1Width = line1Layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
    });
    line2Layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_line2);
    line2Layout.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            line2Width = line2Layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
    });

    keywordEdtTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyword_txt);

    saveButn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    saveButn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            makeKeywordTxt();
        }
    });     
    }

private void makeKeywordTxt()
{
    keywordEdtTxt.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);
            linearLayoutParams.setMargins(7, 0, 0, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
            keywordTxt = new TextView(HomeScreen.this);
            keywordTxt.setText(keywordEdtTxt.getText().toString());
            keywordTxt.setPadding(12, 0, 12, 0);
            keywordTxt.setBackgroundColor(HomeScreen.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_xxlight));
            keywordTxt.setTextColor(HomeScreen.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_value_text));
            keywordTxt.setMaxLines(1);
            keywordTxt.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);

            //Add it to temp layout to get the width
            tempLayout.addView(keywordTxt);
            keywordTxt.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    keywordWidth = keywordTxt.getMeasuredWidth();
                    tempLayout.removeAllViews();
                    addKeyword();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void addKeyword()
{
    if (line1Width - keywordWidth > 25)
    {
        line1Layout.addView(keywordTxt);
        line1Width = line1Width - keywordWidth;
    }
    else if (line2Width - keywordWidth > 30)
    {
        line2Layout.addView(keywordTxt);
        line2Width = line2Width - keywordWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        remaningKeywords.add(keywordTxt);
    }
}
```

And the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_home_screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.aspiresys.facebookaccountkitpoc.HomeScreen">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clipToPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_line2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clipToPadding="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/more"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/keyword_img"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Save"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/keyword_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:ems="10"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/temp_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/save"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```